# How can I put text in a radio button label?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using an array with questions and radio buttons to select the value of the user's choice.

I know how to change the text inside a button dynamically.

`document.getElementById('rad1').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansA;`

But I do not know how to do this when using a label for a radio button .

```
<html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="formEl">
            <h2 id="question"></h2>

            <input type="radio" id="rad1" name="rad" value="choice 1">
            <label for="rad1"></label>

            <input type="radio" id="rad2" name="rad" value="choice 2">
            <label for="rad2"></label>

            <input type="radio" id="rad3" name="rad" value="choice 3">
            <label id="labelRad3"></label>

            <input type="radio" id="rad4" name="rad" value="choice 4">
            <label for="rad4"></label>

            <button id="previous" type="button" class="userSelection">Previous</button>
            <button id="next" type="button" class="userSelection">Next</button>
            <button id="submit">Submit</button>

        </form>
    </body>
    <script src = js/app.js></script>
</html>
```

```javascript
class Question {
    constructor(question, ansA, ansB, ansC, ansD, answer) {
        this.question = question;
        this.ansA = ansA;
        this.ansB = ansB;
        this.ansC = ansC;
        this.ansD = ansD;
        this.answer = answer;
    };

    checkAns(ansSelected, answer) {
        if (ansSelected === answer) {
            console.log('Well Done')
        };
    };
};

//Questions
var questionOne = new Question('Where is Creete?',
                               'Barcalona', 'Greece', 'Dubi', 'Ireland', 'Greece');
var questionTwo = new Question('How many times have Liverppool won the Champions Legue?',
                               '1', '4', '6', '5', '6');
var questionThree = new Question('Where was the first Godfather in the mafia from?',
                                 'Milan', 'Gunoa', 'Rome', 'Napoli', 'Napoli');

//Index of the array with the questions array 
var i = 0;
const arrayQuestion = [questionOne, questionTwo, questionThree];


//Displaying the first index of the question array on load up
document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].question;
document.getElementById('rad1').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansA;
document.getElementById('rad2').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansB;
document.getElementById('labelRad3').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansC;
document.getElementById('rad4').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansD;
```

The result should populate the answers dynamically in their corresponding label

Comment: Why don't you just give the label an ID so you can do it the same way?

Comment: **I know how to change the text inside a button dynamically.** That won't do anything, there's no text inside a radio button.

Comment: No i meant  a `<button>`, but yeah thanks that worked I was getting errors before think I may need a break my brain is like a fried egg :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply give the radio buttons IDs.

```
<label id="rad1-label" for="rad1"></label>
```

Then you can use

```
document.getElementById("rad1-label").innerText = arrayQuestion[i].ansA;
```

Use `innerText` rather than `innerHTML` unless you need HTML tags in the answer to be rendered.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `nextElementSibling` to select `label`s that are exactly next to `radio` inputs. But keep this in mind that this solution completely depends on your HTML structure, if you put anything between `radio input` and `label` this won't work anymore.

```js
class Question {
  constructor(question, ansA, ansB, ansC, ansD, answer) {
    this.question = question;
    this.ansA = ansA;
    this.ansB = ansB;
    this.ansC = ansC;
    this.ansD = ansD;
    this.answer = answer;
  };

  checkAns(ansSelected, answer) {
    if (ansSelected === answer) {
      console.log('Well Done')
    };
  };
};

//Questions
var questionOne = new Question('Where is Creete?', 'Barcalona', 'Greece', 'Dubi', 'Ireland', 'Greece');
var questionTwo = new Question('How many times have Liverppool won the Champions Legue?', '1', '4', '6', '5', '6');
var questionThree = new Question('Where was the first Godfather in the mafia from?', 'Milan', 'Gunoa', 'Rome', 'Napoli', 'Napoli');

//Index of the array with the questions array 
var i = 0;
const arrayQuestion = [questionOne, questionTwo, questionThree];


//Displaying the first index of the question array on load up
document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].question;
document.getElementById('rad1').nextElementSibling.innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansA;
document.getElementById('rad2').nextElementSibling.innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansB;
document.getElementById('rad3').nextElementSibling.innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansC;
document.getElementById('rad4').nextElementSibling.innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansD;
```

```html
<html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="formEl">
    <h2 id="question"></h2>

    <input type="radio" id="rad1" name="rad" value="choice 1">
    <label for="rad1"></label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" id="rad2" name="rad" value="choice 2">
    <label for="rad2"></label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" id="rad3" name="rad" value="choice 3">
    <label for="rad3"></label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" id="rad4" name="rad" value="choice 4">
    <label for="rad4"></label>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <button id="previous" type="button" class="userSelection">Previous</button>
    <button id="next" type="button" class="userSelection">Next</button>
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>

  </form>
</body>
<script src=j s/app.js></script>

</html>
```